# Free variables that are declared inside switch statement blocks

Tags: c

I have a switch statement which declares different variables inside each case block. I want to free these variables at the end of the routine but compiler throw an error that identifier "variable name" is not defined. I do not want to declare these variables before the switch statement. How can I resolve this error? Here is the pseudo code:

```
int CaseType;

switch(CaseType){

Case 1:
{
    double *a = malloc(100 * sizeof(double));
    << some operation here >>
    break;
}

Case 2:
{
    double *b = malloc(200 * sizeof(double));
    << some operation here >>
    break;
}


}

if (CaseType == 1) free(a);
if (CaseType == 2) free(b);
```

Comment: All lifetime of variables in C only exist within their respective scope (*block scope*), they don't exist outside of that.

Comment: There's no one right way to fix this. There are lots of sensible ways to manage dynamic objects in C and you can pick whichever one best fits your use case. I could write an answer picking one randomly, but it might make no sense for your particular use case.

Comment: what is the purpose of doing this

Comment: Do the `free(a)` before the `break` in the `Case 1:` block. Same for `b`.

Comment: You need to free the pointer before the case is exited otherwise the pointer to the allocated memory is lost.  If you assign the pointer to something else that lives longer than the block then you can use that to free the memory.  As posted, this actually looks like something that doesn't even need (and probably shouldn't use) dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Lifetime and scope are different things. Lifetime is **when** during program execution an object exists. Scope is **where** in source code an identifier is visible. An object may exist while code not in the scope of its identifier is executing. This is a correlation between many lifetimes and scopes in that the lifetime of an automatic object ends when execution of its associated block ends (rather than merely is suspended, as occurs during a function call), but they are different and should not be conflated.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Did you read my comment? I never claimed they where the same thing, my comment wouldn't even make sense in that regard. It should be utterly clear that I'm talking about two different things. Otherwise does this sentence make any sense to you? *"All lifetime of variables in C only exist within their respective lifetime"*

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Your comment says “All lifetime of variables in C **only exist within their respective scope**” and “they don’t exist outside of that.” Those are false. In `void bar(int *p) { printf("%d\n", *p}; } void foo(void) { int a = 3; bar(&a); }`, the object identified by `a` exists when `bar` and `printf` are executing. During this time, execution is not within the block that encloses `a`, yet the object it identifies does exist and is accessed by code outside the scope of `a`. It is not correct to say that an object exists only within the scope of its identifiers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No my statement is correct, it appears you don't completely understand what the block scope of a variable is. During the execution of `foo`, `bar` and `printf` are **not** outside the block scope where `a` is. Also if you really believe that perhaps you should mention that in the answers to the question which say the same thing?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: The block in which `a` is defined is `{ int a = 3; bar(&a); }`. The scope of `a` begins just after its declarator (the `a` in `int a`) per C 2011 [N1570] 6.2.1 7 and extends to the end of this block, per 6.2.1 4. The function `bar`, including its body, is not within that scope. Also, I did mention this in a comment to one answer, and the author made edits, after which I deleted the comment. The other answer is not explicitly wrong about lifetime and scope; its use of “referenced” and the imprecise term “variable” could mean the identifier cannot be used outside its scope.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes it is and says so directly in the specification: *"and extends to the end of this block"*. The method call of `bar` happens in the block scope of `a`. It's literally impossible to not be, otherwise `&a` wouldn't work. Scope is determined during complication, how `bar` was declared is not the same thing as the scope it's executed in. The the text in the answer: *"the lifetime of a is entirely within the block specified by the braces {}"*, means the exact same thing as what I said. The only thing they changes was they said "scope" init and made it "lifetime".

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Scope is **where**. Per the C standard, it is “a region of program **text**” (emphasis added). Scope does not extend to other text to which execution flows. Execution is an event (or sequence of events), not a location. Execution occurs over time. The body of `bar` is not within the scope of `a`. Execution of `bar` occurs after execution passes through the start of the scope of `a` and before execution passes through the end of the scope of `a`. However, execution of `bar` is not part of the scope of `a`. The standard explicitly says that execution of the block is suspended…

Comment: … during a function call, so the execution of `bar` is not even part of the execution of the block containing `a`. While `bar` is executing, the block containing `a` is not executing. Scope is **only** locations in program text. It is solely about place, not time. Lifetime is about time. This terminology is consistent throughout the standard, and your use of `scope` to include places outside the text in which the identifier `a` is visible is inconsistent with the C standard.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: To make it even more elementary, objects do not have scopes at all. Identifiers have scopes. Objects have lifetimes. The title of clause 6.2.1 is “Scopes of identifiers,” and paragraph 2 starts “For each different entity that an identifier designates, the identifier is *visible* (i.e., can be used) only within a region of program text called its *scope*.” 6.2.4 1 starts “An object has a *storage duration* that determines its lifetime.” It is very clear they are separate. Identifiers have scopes. Objects have lifetimes.

Answer (score 4):

With regard to code like:

```
case 1:
{
    double *a = malloc(100 * sizeof(double));
    << some operation here >>
    break;
}
```

the *lifetime* of `a` is entirely within the block specified by the braces `{}`. That object does not exist following that block.

It would be more normal to free the variable within the same scope (i.e., immediately before the `break`):

```
case 1: {
    double *a = malloc(100 * sizeof(double));
    << some operation here >>
    free(a);
    break;
}
```

But, on the off-chance you wanted to use it after that point for something else, you could create the objects before the braces so that they're accessible later, something like:

```
double *a = NULL, *b = NULL;

switch(CaseType){
    case 1: {
        a = malloc(100 * sizeof(double));
        << some operation here >>
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        b = malloc(200 * sizeof(double));
        << some operation here >>
        break;
    }
}

// Do something with a and/or b, ensuring they're not NULL first.

free(a);  // freeing NULL is fine if you haven't allocated anything.
free(b);
```

---

As an aside, you should *always* assume that calls subject to failure (like `malloc`) *will* fail at some point and code accordingly. I'll give you the benefit of the doubt that such code exists in the `<< some operation here >>` section :-)

Comment: Your second approach is useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Variables can only be referenced in the code block they were declared in. Because each of your switch cases has its own block, the pointers cannot be freed from outside that block.

There are a couple of ways you can resolve this. For example you could free the pointers at the end of each switch case (before the break), or you could declare the pointer variable before the switch, that way it can be seen from outside it.